# How to check multiple dictionaries for values?

Tags: python

If I have:

```py
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
e = {'a': 2, 'b': 6}
f = {'a': 1, 'b': 4}
```

How would I check that values of the `'b'` key in all dictionaries is above 2 and then execute a function?

I have tried:

```py
dicts = [d, e, f]
for i in dicts:
    if i['b'] >= 3:
        func()
```

However, this calls the function 3 times, whereas I only want to call it once all arguments are met.

Comment: *Count* how many times `i['b'] >= 3` is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dicts = [d, e, f]    
if all([i['b'] >= 3 for i in dicts]):
    func()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to keep track:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
e = {'a': 2, 'b': 6}
f = {'a': 1, 'b': 4}

dicts = [d, e, f]

callFunct = True
for i in dicts:
    if i['b'] < 3:
        callFunct = False

if callFunct:
    func()
```

Another version without a flag was suggested by @Tomerikoo [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437502/how-to-check-multiple-dictionaries-for-values/72437551?noredirect=1#comment127966064_72437551):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
e = {'a': 2, 'b': 6}
f = {'a': 1, 'b': 4}

dicts = [d,e,f]

for i in dicts:
    if i['b'] < 3:
        break
else:
    func()
```

Comment: No flag is needed (`callFunct`). Just put `break` under the `if` and call the function inside an `else` (at the level of the for loop) see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Added your suggested version also. Thanks @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to add a counter that tells you whether the dictionary had the key you were looking for:

```py
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
e = {'a': 2, 'b': 6}
f = {'a': 1, 'b': 4}

dicts = [d,e,f]
counter = 0
for d in dicts:
    if d.get("b") and d["b"] >=3:
        counter += 1

if counter == len(dicts):
    func()
```

Comment: You could just do `if d.get('b', 0) >= 3`. If the key is not there, the condition will be false

Comment: yes, but I'm unsure if the default value should be `0`

Comment: It's `< 3` so it will always be false...